# how do I issue Stop + A command via a putty telnet session for a solaris unix sparcstation (Solaris OS version 4.0)

Tags: operating-systems, telnet, solaris

I am struggling to issue a Stop + A command sequence on a Solaris Sun OS Sparcstation remotely. The ultimate goal is to be able to reboot the host machine without using shutdown or reboot commands. These require sudo permissions or root access and I do not have those.

The Solaris host machine is very old and runs on Solaris Unix Version 4.0. I am trying to issue the command via a remote telnet session to the sun host machine via putty. I am unable to send this command sequence.

The only way I can send this sequence is when I am physically at the Solaris workstation and use the associated Solaris keyboard to press hold the stop and A keys together. This triggers a prompt where I can type boot.

Comment: Are you connected to an out-of-band management interface like LOM, ALOM or ILO? How do you access the machine?

Comment: So this host machine is on its own isolated network in the workplace. It runs telnet server.  I use putty as a telnet client and use the fully qualified host name of this machine to telnet to it (Port 23).

Comment: There was no version 4.0 of the Solaris OS - you should look at `/etc/release` to determine what the actual OS version is.  (There was a SunOS 4.0 back in 1988, but why would you still be running that today?)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. `Stop+A` stops execution of the operating system and returns to OpenBoot PROM. Since you are logged on to the machine via `telnet`, which runs on the operating system, you session would hang or be disconnected. You would lock yourself out of the machine, because you just halted Solaris.

If you want to do something like this, you would have to hook up a [serial console server](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/kvm/serial-console-servers/sn9108/) to the serial port of the system. Then you can send an RS-232 break signal via the serial line to return to OpenBoot PROM.

Btw, I know it was a different time back then, but Sun wasn't so stupid to leave a backdoor like this open and let non-root users remotely reboot the system ;) In fact, most Sun servers of that era have a physical lock on the front of the machine which is used as a power switch. If it's in the locked position, you can't even use a keyboard to send `Stop+A`.

If you have physical access to the system, why not just reset the root password? If you boot to single-user mode (`ok> boot -s`), then you can use `passwd` to change the root password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not have any exposure to system administrative level tasks on the Solaris OS and hence my expertise is quite limited. However, here are my questions/thoughts.

Comment: Since I had mentioned in the original post that I do not have root level permissions, is it still possible to use passwd command on the user prompt? Also could you provide the full steps on what needs to be done after issuing a Stop + A in order to reset the root password in case it is possible to change it as a non-root user? 

With boot -s, are there any caveats that I need to be aware of that would prevent other users from using it after I am done with my tasks in this particular boot mode?

Comment: After the Stop + A, at the user prompt, I usually use the boot command without any switches and hit enter and the system reboots. This is my normal sequence that I use when I have to reboot when I am physically using the host machine.

Comment: As far as buying additional external equipment goes (serial console server), I don't think I would be buying a serial console server and I am sure the cost of purchasing it may not be sufficiently justifiable to the management at my workplace.

Comment: For additional context --> For unknown reasons, the host machine freezes up every couple of days and loses network connectivity. The global IT group at our workplace hasn't been helpful with finding the root cause of the issue. But by trial and error, I know that physically going to the machine and typing Stop + A and typing boot reboots the system and the system is back up and running with an active network connection. At that point, I am able to telnet back in using putty.

Comment: I was hoping that if I could do this remotely, that would be quite helpful instead of needing to do this every single time physically at the workstation for logistical reasons.

Comment: Please do not put additional information in comments, but edit your question instead. If you boot with `boot -s`, you get dropped to a shell. Use `passwd` to change the password. Then use `init 6` to reboot the system into multi-user mode. While in single-user mode, the network will not work and only a single shell can be started on the system (which is why it's called _single_-user mode). I get that you _want_ do to it differently, but the system was literally designed to work this way. Non-root users aren't supposed to reboot the system remotely.